# Matlab: using Textscan to get info from .txt files downloaded from ftp site

Tags: matlab, textscan

I'm writing a function that given the path of a folder, will download all FTP files from this [URL](ftp://ftp3.interactivebrokers.com/) (open in Chrome) and will also return a structure or cell array with the information from those files.

So far, I had no trouble with most of files, but the ones that have lots of rows of data are giving me trouble (for example, 'british.txt'). I cannot read data from files that have 2000 rows and above. For those files who are shorter, I have no problems with.

The relevant part of my function that uses textscan is this:

```
list_txt=dir('*.txt'); %After downloading the files, I list them by its extension.
txt_data=cell(numel(list_txt),8); %pre-allocation of cell array that will store all the info I need from the loop.
for kk=1:numel(list_txt)
    fid=fopen(list_txt(kk).name,'rt');
    txt_single=textscan(fid,'%s %s %s %s %s %f %f %s','Delimiter','|','headerLines', 2);
    fclose(fid);

    [m2,n2]=size(txt_single{1,1});

    for jj=1:n2
        txt_single{1,n2}(m2)=[]; %I want to get rid of the last row that says #EOF   
    end
    txt_data(kk,1:8)=txt_single; %I go and store information of every file per row in this cell array

end
```

Now, I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32095944/textscan-on-file-with-large-number-of-lines) and tried some of the approaches, but I couldn't get any results from it, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

I'll be glad if anyone can help me out on this.

EDIT:

[image: Outcome of matlab function and cell array that it returns]

Some files are not being read in its entirety (british, US, swedish and a couple more).

So I tried performing the operation in the command window, using this code for, let's say, 'british.txt':

```
blockSize=1000;
fid=fopen('british.txt','rt');
txt_single=textscan(fid,'%s %s %s %s %s %f %f %s',blockSize,'Delimiter','|','headerLines', 2);
fclose(fid);
```

The outcome is not even close to what I desire, which is reading around 2000 rows of information.

[image: Trying to read 1000 lines of the file without success]

Comment: What do you mean by "giving me trouble"? And why did the approaches from the linked question not work?

Comment: Hello @hbaderts, what I mean is that some files have around 2000 rows, sometimes even more (the case for US files). I tried reading the file per blocks of 1000, 5000 and 10000 but got the same results. The argument for textscan was similar to the ones presented in that question, but didn't work for me.

Comment: Hello @Aquiles, ok, and what are the results you get? A crash? an error? Could you show your code for reading in blocks of 1000?

Comment: @hbaderts no crash nor errors. I edited the question above, you can see what I used and the outcome when I tried reading one block of 1000 rows.